# How to set the tool tip on jqGrid mouse over?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, tooltip

How can you set the "tool tip" that appears when you hover your mouse over a jqGrid row/cell?

Currently the tool tip appears to just be the cell contents.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In general I agree with Justin, that jqGrid get you no direct way to set tooltip on the row, you can do this only on the cell basis. So you have to do this manually.

First of all you should set [title:false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) property on all cells to have no tooltip for the cells. Then you have to set your custom tooltips of every row. You can do this for example inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle. The corresponding code can be about following:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
        var id=ids[i];
        var rowData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData',id);
        $('#'+id,grid[0]).attr('title', rowData.Name + ' (' +
                                        rowData.Category + ', ' +
                                        rowData.Subcategory + ')');
    }
}
```

You can see the corresponding example you can see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RowTitels.htm).

**UPDATED**: In more late versions of jqGrid there are much more effective way to set custom `title`. It's the usage of `cellattr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408355/315935) for an example) or the usage of `rowattr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935)). I recommend to use `gridview: true` option of jqGrid always. The usage of `cellattr` or `rowattr` together with `gridview: true` allows to create full grid body inclusive of all tooltips which one need *in one modification of the page* (the full HTML fragment of grid body inclusive of all tooltips will be assigned to `innerHTML` property). The usage of `.attr` in the loop follows at least to [reflow](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html) which is expansive (see [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)). So the usage of `cellattr` and `rowattr` in combination with `gridview: true` allow to achieve the best performance.

Comment: I test on your demo, and the tooltip doesn't always show up. For example, hover on row #1, then #2, then #1. How can the code be improved to always show the tooltip?

Comment: @eugene y: In what browser you have the problem? In my tests I see tooltip always.

Comment: It was Firefox 3.6.15   Will check some other browsers later.

Comment: @eugene y: I could seen effects of instability of tooltips in FF 4.0 RCm, but I see the same problem in any tooltips: the the standard jqGrid for example. I don't know th reason. Probably it is a **bug in Firefox**. Look at [this post](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7435).

Comment: Yeah, seems to be a bug in FF. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @eugene y: You are welcome! But I didn't really solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no jqGrid API for this. If you want to change the tooltip text you will have to write code to manually change the value of the cell's `title` element.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, where jQuery just WOULD NOT recognize a mouseover even though the class was set correctly.  As a test I setup

```
$('.note).mouseover(function(){alert('hello')})
```

No results.  Then I changed it to

```
$('.note').live('mouseover',function(){alert('hello')})
```

and it worked. It was all about loading order. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight and assign a tooltip to an entire row, using jqgrid 4.4 and IE 11, this works.

1. turn off tooltip in all cells when defining the colModel, for example:

   colModel: [ { name: 'ColumnName', title: false },...
2. assign a loadComplete method to the grid:

   ```
   loadComplete: function () {
   var rows = $(this).getDataIDs();

   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
       var row = $(this).getRowData(rows[i]);
       if (row.IsSomething == 'true') {
           this.rows[i + 1].className = this.rows[i + 1].className + ' ui-state-highlight';
           $(this.rows[i + 1]).attr('title', 'This tooltip will appear for the entire row');
       }
   }
   ```

   }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom formatter

```
        function myCellFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {           
                return '<span title="' + rowObject.name + rowObject.category +rowObject.subcategory +'">'+ cellvalue +'</span>';

        }
```

And then use this formatter in the col model

```
{index: 'name', name: 'name',formatter:myCellFormatter, label: 'Name'},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend my answer for using `bootstrap` tooltip with jqGrid. Grid sets a tooltip by default which could be cleared using `title:false` for each column.

To select a particular `td` or `cell` we could create our own class/attribute using `cellattr` property as a function for any cell. For example:

```
cellattr: function(rowID,val,rawObject,cm,rdata) {
    return "class='tooltip-cell';" // could return 'n' number of attributes
}
```

Then finally, bootstrap function `tooltip` could be called on a single or a collection of `cells/td`:

```
$('#myGrid .tooltip-cell').tooltip({
            container:'body',
            placement: 'bottom',
            title: 'Click to edit',
            trigger: 'hover'
        });
```

`container:body` needs to be used to maintain the behavior of `html` tables.