# Tooltip for struts2 jqGrid column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, tooltip, struts2-jquery-grid

I have to add a custom tooltip to jqGrid's first column. Exactly as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308440/2408092).

```
loadComplete: function() {
var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
    var id=ids[i];
    var rowData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData',id);
    $('#'+id,grid[0]).attr('title', rowData.Name + ' (' +
                                    rowData.Category + ', ' +
                                    rowData.Subcategory + ')');
   }
}
```

But the problem is I am unable to implement it in my grid column

```
<sjg:gridColumn  name="case_no" index="case_no" title="CaseNo" 
editable="true" sortable="true" formatter="formatLink"/>
```

Please suggest me how to add it to the
`$.subscribe('loadComplete', function(event, data) {}`

Thanks.

Comment: So the difference is, that you want it in a column, and not a row?

Comment: @meskobalazs actually i want the result exactly as in the answer. Only thing is how do I call that method in subscribe?

Comment: I found the docs, I'm taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally understand your exact problem. I could not try the solution myself, so this is only based on the documentation. First you define your grid, and set a topic:

```
<sjg:grid
    ...
    onCompleteTopics="loadComplete"
>
```

Then, you can subscribe:

```
$.subscribe('loadComplete', function (event, data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: @m actualy I am usings struts2 jqGrid. So I have set up the grid using tags.  
ie `<sjg:grid id="xyz" caption="xyz"     href="%{remoteurl}" pager="true" pagerButtons="true"
loadonce="true" loadingText="Data Loading" draggable="true"
      gridModel="affi_list" rowList="10,15,20,30,50" rowNum="15" .... >`

 Thats the reason I am fining it difficult to use the above mentioned code

Comment: In that case I am unable to help at this time

Comment: @m No problem and thnks for giving it a try